# Joining two database tables with laravel eloquent

Tags: json, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables in my database: `Agency` and `Vehicle`. Each vehicle belongs to an agency and an agency has many vehicles. Here are my models:

`Agency` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Agency extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'location'];

    public function trains(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vehicle');
    }
}
```

`Vehicle` model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'agency_id', 
        'registration_number', 
        'description'
    ];

    public function agency(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Agency');
    }
}
```

Now how can I return a json object with containing each `train` with its corresponding agency from my controller? Do I have to join the tables based on the agency_id? What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it using [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and [`toJson()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json) as:

```
Agency::with('trains')->get()->toJson();
```